# Interpolation of derivatives

Tags: interpolation, sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

If $U$ is an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ is an $L^2(U)$ function with **second** derivative $f'' \in L^2(U)$ (in the weak sense), is $f \in W^{1,1}(U)$?

EDIT: Removed false inequality.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to fix the TeX...

Comment: I think linear functions might break your inequality what with the zero second derivative and non-zero first derivative. 

Comment: I fixed your LaTeX, but don't immediately see how to fix your inequality

Comment: You are totally right, that inequality is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume $U$ is a *finite* open interval, else the assertion is clearly false (let $f(x)=x$).

Then a standard estimate shows that $f'$ is bounded, and thus in $L^1(U)$, whence $f$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(U)$ (in fact in $W^{1,p}(U)$ for all $p$).

Fix some $x_0 \in U$, and write
$$
\left|f'(x) - f'(x_0)\right| = \left| \int_{x_0}^x f''(y) dy \right|
\leq \| f'' \|_2 \phantom. |x-x_0|^{1/2},
$$
using Cauchy-Schwarz in the last step.  Since $\| f'' \|_2$ is a finite constant and $|x-x_0|$ is bounded, so is $\left|f'(x) - f'(x_0)\right|$, and we are done.

This kind of argument is of course well-known, and probably predates Sobolev himself, but is easier to write up than to look up.  A reader better versed in the literature may be able to supply a canonical reference.

Comment: This argument also shows that $f'$ is of Hölder class $C^{0, 1/2}$ and in particular is continuous.  So the conclusion is that $f$ belongs to $C^{1, 1/2}$, and in particular is continuously differentiable.